# Cannot convert type System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<SelectListItem> to System.Collections.Generic.List<SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following view that I am trying to build dropdownlist from ViewBag.Catagories:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId, List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Catagories,
     new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Here, is the Action in which I have a ViewBag with a list:

```
public ActionResult CreateEdit(int id = 0)
{
    var context = new FeedbackContext();
    ViewBag.Catagories = context.Categories.Select(
        x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
    if (id != 0)
    {
        return View(context.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id));
    }
 }
```

Here, it can populate the categories in the dropdownlist for the first time, but when I validate/resubmit it, it will throw an error.

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'

Please suggest why I am getting an error here .

Comment: Because in the POST method you do not assign`ViewBag.Categories` the same way you are in the GET method (you have not shown the relevant code in the POST method)

Comment: I assume you omitted the `.ToList()` in the POST method code. Although you may as well use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)` in the view and omit `.ToList()`

Comment: Sorry I did not mention the POSTmethod in the question. But, I did added this:         'ViewBag.Catagories = context.Categories.Select(
                x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = x.Name,
                    Value = x.Id.ToString()
                });'

Comment: Exactly! Add `.ToList()` and it will work fine.